# GitPosh dosnt have permission to VSTS remote: TF401019

Tags: git, azure-devops

I created a new folder Test.
run command: git init
then I setUp global configuration - mail and name
then I added:

> git remote add origin https://bvcdata.visualstudio.com/_git/MyRepo
>   git push -u origin --all

and immediately get error:

> remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier sdsdsd does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
>   fatal: repository 'https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_git/MyRepo/' not found

I am the owner of the project on VSTS, so I have all privilegies. It all was working till now.
Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Please check (or ask the VSTS admin to check) if you have permission to contribute to the git repo.

Comment: Has you problem has been solved yet?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Yes, for some reason git posh dont have a possibility to change logged user through console (powershell for example)

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same problem. Can you tell us how to fix this issue in more details please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR:

- Delete the `%LocalAppData%\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache` file on your machine
- If that's not enough, run `git credential-manager clear <repo url>`

This error message came up for me when the repository credentials Git had cached became stale.

Diagnostic stages for me were:

1. Do I have access to the repository?  Check this by browsing to the Code part of your VSTS repository. [image]
2. If I think I've cleared the Git credential cache (which I first did by just deleting the tenant.cache file), am I prompted for credentials when doing a command-line `git fetch`?

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and I fixed it by following steps:

1. empty the old .git-credentials file. my path is ~/.git-credentials.
2. execute `git config --global credential.helper store`.
3. execute `git clone <your git url>` it will ask your username and password.
4. success

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was in using the organization account. I removed the organization qualifier and cloned the repository by **my username** after generating custom credentials from the provided option on devops.

The remote URL was changed from::

https://**OrgAccount**@dev.azure.com/Org1/Project/_git/Mobile%20App

To::

https://**Jainam**@dev.azure.com/Org1/Project/_git/Mobile%20App

--

And it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble and to repair it, i have removed some generic credentials into :
Control Panel -> identification manager -> generic credential

in french version :
panneau de configuration -> gestionnaire d'identification -> informations d'identification windows

The trouble come from my git mail connexion have been moved to another and windows store it and use last every time it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another option for solution that worked for us.

1. Opening Windows' **Credential Manager**
2. Moving to **Windows Credentials** tab
3. On 'Generic Credentials' removing the entry that starts with 'git:',
   You probably see 'git:https://'

[image]