# Permissions Error using API command to get Workitems for a Pull Request

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request, workitem

I am trying to get all workitems, linked to all pull requests in a repo.

First, I run the API Command to get all Pull Requests:
   https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/pullrequests?api-version=5.1

That works just fine.

Then Looping through each Pull Request, I try to get all Work Items 
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/workitems?api-version=5.1

Even though I am an Admin, I still get this error:
innerException
:
null
message
:
TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier {MY Repo ID} does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
typeName
:
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitRepositoryNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server
typeKey
:
GitRepositoryNotFoundException
errorCode
:
0
eventId
:
300

Can Anyone help me figure out how to get these related work items for the pull requests?

API Web Pages:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: MAybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50789785/6309

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.

When using the API call to get the workitems for a given Pull Request,  I was using the RepoID field that I got back from the previous command.
Instead of using RepoID as the Repo ID in the New Command to get work items, I had to use the Repo Name.

SO the solution is to use this:
value.0.repository.name
instead of this:
value.0.repository.id
from the first call to get pull requests.